# mysql count field 1 when field 2 =

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following table

**feeder_bouts2**

```
id|feeder|rfid       |bout_time           |success|
1 |   2  | 123456789 |2013-01-07 80:00:00 |  1    |
```

I am running the following query

```
select count(*), feeder 
from feeder_bouts2 
where bout_time >='2013-01-01 8:00:00'
    and rfid !='123456789' and success ='1'
group by feeder;
```

This works perfectly, however I would like to select the same output but only the output for multiple specific feeders e.g. feeder 1,2,3,4,6,7,8 something like

```
select count(*), feeder 
from feeder_bouts2 
where bout_time >='2013-01-01 8:00:00' 
    and rfid !='123456789' and success ='1' 
    and feeder = '1,2,3,4,8,9,10' 
group by feeder;
```

Thanking everyone in advance

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: @njk: Okay but I was hoping the OP would learn how to do it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's a frivolous expectation.

Comment: @njk: There is a time in the history of every single user on Stack Overflow, yourself included, when that user hadn't yet learnt to format a question. Expecting this user to be capable of following the trend of millions, when prompted, is hardly "frivolous".

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`

```
select count(*), feeder 
from feeder_bouts2 
where bout_time >='2013-01-01 8:00:00' 
and rfid !='123456789' 
and success ='1' 
and feeder in (1,2,3,4,8,9,10)
group by feeder;
```